# Check checkboxes with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this html, I need to select a particular check-box based on one parameter. Let's say my parameter is 15, so I need to find data-id=15 and then get the checkbox associated and check programmatically this checkbox. I'm trying to use jquery but I'm not very familiar with that. I need to start searching from div with id="org_container_1".

```
<div class="department-container" id="org_container_1">
            <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="14">                    
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">                    
                    <span class="department-item">Org1</span>
                </label>                                        
            </div>
            <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="15">                    
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">                    
                    <span class="department-item">Org2</span>
                </label>                                        
            </div>
            <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="16">                    
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">                    
                    <span class="department-item">Org3</span>
                </label>                                        
            </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Don't expect much help without at least making an attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: use $.each() jquery method to loop through each div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative:

```js
var param='15';
$('.department-container .department-row').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-id')==param){
        $('input', this).attr('checked','checked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="department-container" id="org_container_1">
    <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="14">                    
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">                    
                    <span class="department-item">Org1</span>
                </label>                                        
            </div>
            <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="15">                    
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">                    
                    <span class="department-item">Org2</span>
                </label>                                        
            </div>
            <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="16">                    
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">                    
                    <span class="department-item">Org3</span>
                </label>                                        
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectors to select your div with the data-id using a data attribute selector `[data-attribute-name=data-attribute-value]`. Then select the checkbox with `input[type=checkbox]`, and use the `.prop()` function to check it.

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $('div[data-id=15] input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="department-container" id="org_container_1">
  <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="14">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="department-item">Org1</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="15">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="department-item">Org2</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="row department-row" data-typeid="1" data-id="16">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="department-item">Org3</span>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var param = 15;
$('[data-id="' + param + '"]').find('input').prop('checked',true);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba86d1ff/)

Answer (score 0):

so you want to use 2 things here. first is the proper jquery selector, and the second is setting the `#attr('checked', true)`:

```
$('div[data-id="' + id + '"] input[type=checkbox').attr('checked', true)
```

(youd want to wrap this in a function of course, but since you havnt provided what your js looks like, i dont have any context of where youre calling this)